# Getting unexpected result in strtotime and date function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
$selectedDate = "1365465600";
echo $selectedDate;//Output : 1365465600
echo date("Y-m-d",$selectedDate);//Output : 2013-04-09
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$selectedDate));//Output : 1365445800
```

Why the last statement didn't produce the output: `1365465600`. What is wrong here?

Comment: Because of Hours, minutes and seconds, which you're ignoring

Answer (score 2):

please try below code you will get exact result

```
$selectedDate = "1365465600";
echo $selectedDate;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$selectedDate);
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$selectedDate));
```